# `-:55: HTML parser error : htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'`: clean up HTML file with xmllint?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, tidy, xmllint, htmltidy

http://journals.im.ac.cn/cjbcn/ch/reader/view_abstract.aspx?file_no=gc19010159&flag=1

I'd like to clean up the file from the above URL. But xmllint gives the following error. Does anybody know how to fix the problem? Thanks.

```
$ xmllint -html -xmlout file.html
-:55: HTML parser error : htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'
ges/dh-img.jpg"><A href="../common_item.aspx?parent_id=20070610225413001&menu_id
                                                                               ^
-:55: HTML parser error : htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'
on_item.aspx?parent_id=20070610225413001&menu_id=20070610225740001&is_three_menu
                                                                               ^
-:55: HTML parser error : htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'
ges/dh-img.jpg"><A href="../common_item.aspx?parent_id=20070610225449001&menu_id
                                                                               ^
-:55: HTML parser error : htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'
on_item.aspx?parent_id=20070610225449001&menu_id=20171222045531778&is_three_menu
                                                                               ^
-:55: HTML parser error : htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'
ges/dh-img.jpg"><A href="../common_item.aspx?parent_id=20070610225428001&menu_id
                                                                               ^
-:55: HTML parser error : htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a problem with the ampersand character used in URLs with query parameters which xmllint wants to interpret as entity reference, and then complains about because entity references in XML must be terminated by a semicolon character (unlike in SGML where a semicolon is required only if subsequent characters are name characters). You could try xmllint's "-noent" option, but I don't believe xmllint can be told to ignore entity references and suggest to use another tool to convert HTML into XML such as "sgmlproc" as described  in my [Parsing HTML tutorial](http://sgmljs.net/docs/parsing-html-tutorial/parsing-html-tutorial.html). Dealing with ampersand chars is discussed in detail there and involves using an HTML DTD where href and other URL-typed attributes are declared such that no entity references are recognized.

Sorry for the long answer and self-promotion, but I know of no better solution for your problem. I originally intended this to be a comment but ran out of space.

Comment: Could you show me the exact command to run it? I tried `sgmlproc -- -o 1.html  view_abstract.aspx\?file_no\=gc19010159\&flag\=1`. But it hangs there.

Comment: Ah, your file has its own DOCTYPE (sgmlproc doesn't hang but fails to download referenced entities). Anyway it isn't valid XHTML. I replaced the DOCTYPE by `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">` (where `about:legacy-compat` refers to the HTML5.2 declarations built-in into `sgmlproc`. Now `sgmlproc` complains about a `B` end-element tag in line 76. Remove the stray `</b>` with no matching start-tag there. Also remove all `nowrap` tokens in the file and remove the bogus `script` element at the end of the file. Then `sgmlproc` will *still* output errors but no fatal ones and create 1.xml

Comment: One additional thing: rename the file into having a .html suffix else sgmlproc won't recognize predefined HTML character entities. Also, you should use `-v output_format=xml` (before `--`) to create XML (see also the detailed discussion about creating proper XHML in the linked tutorial).

Comment: I don't want to make any manual changes to the original file as I will have any files that have errors. Could you show me the exact command to fix the error?

Comment: Sorry but the file is just too broken to be fixed automatically (claiming to be XHTML when it doesn't even have a single root element, containing unbalanced elements, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is for future reference: it turns out that encoding the '&' as entity resolves the htmlParseEntityRef problem in the particular HTML file from the Chinese journal.

A simple example follows illustrating a workaround via perl:

```
$ cat bad-simple.html 
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>bad URL links </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://www.fubar.com?fubar=1&fu=0&bar=0">fubar</a>
  </body>
</html>
$ 
$ xmllint --html --noout bad-simple.html
bad-simple.html:7: HTML parser error : htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'
    <a href="http://www.fubar.com?fubar=1&fu=0&bar=0">fubar</a>
                                            ^
bad-simple.html:7: HTML parser error : htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'
    <a href="http://www.fubar.com?fubar=1&fu=0&bar=0">fubar</a>
                                                  ^
$ perl -pe 's/\&(?!amp)/&amp;/g;' bad-simple.html >| better-simple.html
$ xmllint --html --noout better-simple.html
$ 
$ diff bad-simple.html better-simple.html 
7c7
<     <a href="http://www.fubar.com?fubar=1&fu=0&bar=0">fubar</a>
---
>     <a href="http://www.fubar.com?fubar=1&amp;fu=0&amp;bar=0">fubar</a>
```